# I've installed gcc 4.6.1 on lion, do I overwrite default gcc?

Tags: linux, macos, gcc

I (more or less) followed the instructions here http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/09/20/compiling-gcc-4-6-1-on-mac-osx-lion/ to install a more recent version of gcc so that I can build ruby on a new machine.

So I now have gcc installed to ~/my_gcc, and the instructions say to access gcc in this location by running

```
export PATH=$HOME/my_gcc/bin:$PATH
```

I did this, but am still getting the old gcc when I check the version.

```
$ gcc -v
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
```

If I move the gcc in /usr/bin/gcc to gcc_old, I don't get any gcc recognized even though when I echo $PATH the ~/my_gcc/bin path does show up.  Should I just copy ~/my_gcc/bin to /usr/bin?

Comment: Did you put that `export` in your `~/.bashrc`?  Have you opened a new terminal? (Does `echo $PATH` show that path?)

Comment: Try `which gcc`. Are the files you compiled maybe not executable?

Answer (score 1):

I hacked around this using a previous method (ran into the EXACT same problem) and unfortunately I could not come up with a non hacky solution.. however:

Using `which gcc` will tell you where the default installed gcc is. Now if I were you, I would move the old gcc to a new directory and create a symbolic link to the new gcc directory in the old directory.

Try `gcc -v`again after that.

Sorry for the illegitimate  method. I have yet to come up with a clean solution.

+1 to anyone who does if I see it.

Good luck

Comment: I found a non hacky version, which is that there is a site with dmgs for installing gcc on mac.  Not only does it install cleanly, but it doesn't take 2 hours to install (more like 5 minutes).  Unbelievably, it is so buried in terms of google results that I can't even find the link to provide here!!  Gah, if anyone could add it.. it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed the procedure [described here](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/09/20/compiling-gcc-4-6-1-on-mac-osx-lion/), you should inquire for `my-gcc`, `my-g++`, `my-gfortran` and so on. The author has purposely added the "my-" prefix in order to not mess up Apple's compilers.

```
my-gcc -v
```

should return `gcc-4.6.1` or `4.6.2`.